# Как в Yii2 использовать метод toArray() для набора моделей, которые были получены с использованием with()

Tags: yii2, сериализация

На пример есть модель Author у которого есть связь Book;
Получаю набор авторов:

`$books = Book::find()->with('author')->all();`

В итоге, если использовать `toArray()`, то для каждой модели Book фреймворк выполняет еще один запрос в поисках автора;

Очень не удобно, для разработки rest/api

Comment: Это ожидаемое поведение. Чего в итоге вы хотите добиться?

Comment: механизм with подразумевает, что все авторы будут извлечены одним запросом

Comment: @АртемБондаренкопокажите связь и метод toArray если он переопределялся

Comment: связь описана стандартно:
public function getAuthor(){
        return $this->hasOne(Author::className(),['id'=>'author_id']);
    }
toArray() не переопределен

Answer (score 0):

Использовать `relation` не очень хорошая идея (в этом месте я уже предчувствую как набегут `эксперты`, заминусят мой ответ и словесно сожгут меня на костре за этакое мракобесие :) ) Объясню почему. Представьте `GridView` и в одной из его ячеек Вам нужно вывести через `relation` данные из связанной таблицы. Это будет на каждую запись в `GridView` еще один запрос к БД вида `select from where id =`. Да Вы можете настроить `нежадную` выборку - тогда запрос будет всего один, но вида `select from where id IN(id1,id2...idN)`, что тоже не очень быстрый запрос в зависимости от СУБД конечно.

Я бы Вам посоветовал в модели реализовать отдельный метод в котором Вы сами будете получать сразу все данные (по-странично, с группировками, сортировками и тп) максимально оптимизированным запросом и даже сразу в массив :)
Например

```php
/**
* @return array
*/
public function getAuthorsList() {
    return ( new Query() )->select(['a.id', 'a.firstname', 'a.secondname', 'a.lastname'])->from(Authors::tableName().' a')->innerJoin( LnkBookAuthors::tableName().' b2a', 'b2a.author_id = a.id' )->innerJoin( Books::tableName().' b', 'b2a.book_id = b.id' )->all();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне в принципе и "нежадный" вариант вполне устраивает, но вопрос был в том, как коробочный сериализатор заставить его использовать

Comment: используйте `ArrayHelper::map`